# Access fragment controls from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `FragmentActivity` that should hold 2 `Fragments`. Each fragment has it's own layout with a table in it. I need to access the tables from the fragments' layouts from within the `FragmentActivity` to put some data that I read from an XML file. My problem is that when I use

`tableOrders = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabel1);`

it returns `null`. Now, I know that items from layouts can only be accessed before they have been inflated, and I've done that in the FragmentActivity before trying to call `findViewById()`. Here is the code for what I've tried:

---

The onCreate of the `FragmentHolder.java` that is derived from `FragmentActivity`:

```
    private TableLayout tableOrders = null;
   private TableLayout tableExecutions = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_holder);
    initialisePaging();

    //View orderFragment = (View)findViewById(R.layout.fragment_orders);        
    tableOrders = (TableLayout)/*orderFragment.*/findViewById(R.id.tabel1);
    //View execFragment = (View)findViewById(R.layout.executions_fragment);
    tableExecutions = (TableLayout)/*execFragment.*/findViewById(R.id.tabel2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null)
        logedUser = (User) bundle.getSerializable("user");

    AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();

    String xmlContentOrders = XMLfunctions.getXml(am, "ordersData.xml");
    populateOrdersTable(xmlContentOrders);

    String xmlContentExecutions = XMLfunctions.getXml(am, "executionsData.xml");
    populateExecutionsTable(xmlContentExecutions);
}
```

---

The fragment class (don't know if it helps):

```
    public class OrdersFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);
     return view;
    }
    }
```

---

The fragment class (don't know if it helps):

```
   public class OrdersFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);
     return view;
    }
    }
```

---

And the .xml file for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabel1header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tablebgcolor" >

    <TableRow  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ordersHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/orders"
            android:textStyle="bold"                />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/ordersTable"
        style="@style/HeaderRow" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSymbol"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/symbol"
            style="@style/HeaderText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/side"
            style="@style/HeaderText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/price"
            style="@style/HeaderText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textQuantity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/quantity" 
            style="@style/HeaderText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRemaining"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/remanent"
            style="@style/HeaderText" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabel1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@color/tablebgcolor">
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

With that said hope someone has a solution for this (probably it's something easy that I missed).

---

Edit: The code I use to put the Fragments on the FragmentActivity:

```
private void initialisePaging() {

    OrdersFragment fragmentOne = new OrdersFragment();
    ExecutionsFragment fragmentTwo= new ExecutionsFragment();

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentOne);
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentTwo);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Comment: How are you putting the `Fragment`s in your `Activity`? Are you calling the FragmentManager or are you including them in the XML? You can always retrieve the Fragments by code and access its inner members that way.

Comment: I am putting the `Fragments`s in the `Activity` using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` derived class. I'll update the post with the code for that function. And how can I access the fragments inner member through code?